# Most efficient way to encode presence of elements of a list in another list

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Suppose I have a **sorted** main list like this:
`main = ["a", "b", "cd", "e"]`

And a bunch of other lists like `l1 = ["a", "cd"]` and `l2 = ["b", "cd"]`. It's also guaranteed that all elements of the individual lists like `l1` and `l2` also belong to `main`. *Not all individual lists have to be of the same length, but all of them are smaller than or equal to `main` in length.*

Now for each individual list, I want to create a vector that encodes which elements of `main` are present in the individual list. e.g. for `l1`, we'll get a vector (numpy array) `[1,0,1,0]` since the first and third elements (I can say "first" and "third" because `main` is sorted) of `main`. Similarly for `l2` we'll get `[0,1,1,0]`.

What's an efficient way to do this? I don't want the naive brute force approach because that'll be insanely slow. Are there any intermediary numpy conversions/operations involved? Would be glad to get help on this!

Comment: Can it have `["a", "a", "a"]`? What is the expected output of it?

Comment: Typically how many such individual lists would you have?

Comment: @Divakar: Around 600000. Main list has approx 4000 elements.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar: I've used numpy.isin() because I had to wrap that functionality in another function, and np.isin is very easy to implement (built-in one-liner) and seems efficient too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out you can use `np.isin`

```
def isin_many_np(main, L):
    return np.array([np.isin(main, l) for l in L])
```

But if you are going to do this many times it's more efficient to use a dictionary giving for each element of main its position.

Then you just have to write the following:

```
def isin_dict(main_d, L):
    r = np.zeros(len(main_d), dtype=bool)
    for li in L:
      r[main_d[li]] = 1
    return r

def isin_many_dict(main, L):
    main_d = {s:i for i,s in enumerate(main)}
    return np.array([isin_dict(main_d, l) for l in L]).view('i1')
```

And here some benchmark against `np.isin` and @Divakar's answer:

```
import random
import string

main = sorted([''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 5)) for i in range(4000)])
L = [random.sample(main, 2000) for i in range(6000)]

%timeit t = isin_many_np(main, L)                                                                                                                
6.67 s ± 121 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit r = isin_many_divakar(main, L)                                                                                                                      
2.17 s ± 50.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit s = isin_many_dict(main, L)                                                                                                               
1.27 s ± 11.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use list comprehension:

```
main = ["a", "b", "cd", "e"]
l1 = ["a", "cd"]

print ([item in l1 for item in main])
```

output:

```
[True, False, True, False]
```

or

```
print ([1 if item in l1 else 0 for item in main])
```

output:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with `np.searchsorted` -

```
def isin_many(main, L):
    # main is the array or list where presence is to be detected
    # L is list of lists whose presence is to be detected
    main_ar = np.asarray(main)

    La = np.concatenate(L)
    sidx = np.argsort(main_ar)
    idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(main_ar, La, sorter=sidx)]

    n = len(L)
    out = np.zeros((n,len(main_ar)), dtype=bool)
    row = np.repeat(np.arange(n),np.array([len(l) for l in L]))
    out[row,idx] = True
    return out.view('i1')
```

Output would be a `2D` array, each row of which would give us the presence of each individual list in the main list. It's mostly a vectorized method (only looping is to get the length of individual lists, which would be computationally negligible), given the number of such lists is a big number.

Sample run -

```
In [44]: main = ["a", "b", "cd", "e", "F"]
    ...: l1 = ["a", "cd"]; l2 = ["b", "cd"]; l3 = ['F']

In [45]: isin_many(main, [l1,l2,l3])
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], # presence of l1
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], # presence of l2 and so on ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! One more thing though - what if I have NaN values in both the main list and one of the individual lists? I've read that it's good practice to always keep NaN values in mind, so I'd like to ignore (assign a 0 to) the index corresponding to NaN values in an individual list. Is that possible?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari So, would that be numpy.nan or 'nan'(string) or None?

Answer (score 1):

you can try if else in list comprehension with numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

#encode presence of elements of a list in another list
def list_contains(mainlist, otherlist):
    result = np.array([1 if x in otherlist else 0 for x in mainlist])
    return result
```

you can check with

```
main = ["a", "b", "cd", "e"]
l1 = ["a", "cd"]
l2 = ["b", "cd"]

#check 1
out1 = list_contains(main, l1)
print(out1)  # [1 0 1 0]
type(out1)  # numpy.ndarray

#check 2
out2 = list_contains(main, l2)
print(out2)  # [0 1 1 0]
type(out2)  # numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution used **numpy isin** (it gives True/False), efficiency wise, as in many cases, it depends on size, list comprehension is faster in your small example but much slower in longer cases, here goes:

```
import itertools
import string
import random 
import numpy as np

main = ["a", "b", "cd", "e"]
l1 = ["a", "cd"]

def f1(main, l):
    return [1 if x in l else 0 for x in main]

%%timeit
f1(main, l1)
output: 649 ns ± 15.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
np.isin(main, l1)
output:23 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and to the long example:

```
letters_and_couples = \
[''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, 2)]+\
[''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)]

long_main = random.choices(letters_and_couples,k=1000000)
long_l1 = random.choices(letters_and_couples,k=1000)

%%timeit
f1(long_main, long_l1)
output: 5.02 s ± 71.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
np.isin(long_main, long_l1)
output: 241 ms ± 1.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```